# realpath() open_basedir restriction in effect.

Tags: zend-framework, vps, open-basedir

I'm trying to get my Zend Framework application up and running on my VPS. I'm receiving this error:

**Error**

Warning: realpath() [function.realpath]: open_basedir restriction in effect.

Apparently this is quite common with Plesk's default restrictions so I'm sure some of you have faced the same problem.

**What I've tried**

In /var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN/conf/ I have created the file vhost.conf using the Virtuozzo Power Panel. Below is the code that I placed in vhost.conf:

**Attempt 1**

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN/public>
<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
        php_admin_value open_basedir none
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_admin_value open_basedir none
</IfModule>
</Directory>
```

**Attempt 2**

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN/public>
    php_admin_value open_basedir none
</Directory>
```

I've also restarted the httpd service.

**Folder structure**

My folder structure is as follows:

```
/var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN/application
/var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN/library
/var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN/public
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need to set the `open_basedir` for the entire project:

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN>
    php_admin_value open_basedir none
</Directory>
```

You will also need to set the `DocumentRoot` to:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN/public"
```

though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem & solved it without setting open_basedir to none.
You can add multiple paths to open_basedir by separating them with ":" in Linux and ";" in Windows. So if "realpath" is mentioned in your warning add "realpath" to your open_basedir setting or a parent directory of "realpath". For example like that:

```
php_admin_value open_basedir "/srv/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs:/tmp:/usr/share/php5/"
```

Now your open_basedir is configured with 3 paths:

```
/srv/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs
/tmp
/usr/share/php5
```

In my case the last path of the 3 above was needed for zend to run on my system without warnings.

Also notice that there is a difference between ending your path with "/" or not !
Without the "/" all subfolders will be included to open_basedir.
Take a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Lucian